# How to incorporate prior knowledge into a CNN?

Tags: neural-networks, prior, bayesian-network, convolution

I'm pretty new to Bayesian inference and machine learning, so I think I'm just lacking the right words to search for a paper that addresses this topic, so here goes:

I'm trying to do image segmentation using a CNN. However, I have some prior knowledge about the likely class for each pixel. So for a given image X that I am training a model to segment, for each pixel of X I have a value for the believed classification and a confidence value that measures how confident I am in that guess. (This "prior" is precomputed and comes from a separate data source that relates to the image set.) How do I formulate this knowledge and incorporate into an image segmentation neural net? Is this possible?